# useEffect uses old dependency value - using IntersectionObserver (iOS browsers only)

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, mobile-website, intersection-observer

I'm using IntersectionObserver to fetch data when `div` at the end of a product list is visible. I'm also using redux to store data.
Here's a core of my component.

```
export default function Home() {
   const [isLoadingMore, setIsLoadingMore] = useState(false)
   const { activeCategoryId, products, page } = useSelector((state) => state.pages.homePage)

   const observerTarget = useRef(null)

   useEffect(() => {
    const loadMoreProducts = async () => {
      if (isLoadingMore || page === '') {
        return
      }

      setIsLoadingMore(true)

      const response = await productService.getProducts({
        category: activeCategoryId,
        page: page,
      })

      if (response.isOk && response.data) {
        dispatch(
          PagesActions.setHomePage({
            products: [...products, ...response.data.results],
            page: response.data.next || '',
          })
        )
        // Stop observing if there are no more products to load
        if (response.data.results.length === 0) {
          observer.unobserve(observerTarget.current)
        }
      }

      setIsLoadingMore(false)
    }

    const observer = new IntersectionObserver(
      (entries) => {
        if (entries[0].isIntersecting) {
          loadMoreProducts()
        }
      },
      { threshold: 1 }
    )

    if (observerTarget.current) {
      observer.observe(observerTarget.current)
    }

    return () => {
      if (observerTarget.current) {
        observer.unobserve(observerTarget.current)
      }
    }
  }, [activeCategoryId, dispatch, page, observerTarget, products, isLoadingMore])

  const switchMainCategory = (category) => {
    dispatch(
      PagesActions.setHomePage({ products: [], page: null, activeCategoryId: category?.code })
    )
  }

  return (
    // here we have a list of categories, list of products and observerTarget div
  )
}
```

When `switchMainCategory()` is called by clicking the category in categories list, `activeCategoryId`, `products` and `page` should be changed which should trigger useEffect hook to call `loadMoreProducts()`.
And it does call it, but on iOS browsers, previous `activeCategoryId` is passed to `loadMoreProducts()` and `page` is increased instead of being set to `null`.

This works correctly on desktop and android browsers, new category products are fetched on category change. The issue appears only on iOS browsers.
Why is that, is there anything else I'm missing here that's specific to iOS devices?